# How do I do foreach loop with a where clause for a multidimensional array in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

For example

```sh
$people = @(
 @('adam', '24', 'M')
 @('andy', '20', 'M')
 @('alex', '30', 'M')
 @('ava', '25', 'F')
)

foreach($person in $people | where ($person[1] -lt '25') -and ($person[2] -eq 'M'))
```

and this should select `adam` and `andy`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax you should use for your `Where-Object` statement would be:

```sh
$people = @(
    @('adam', '24', 'M'),
    @('andy', '20', 'M'),
    @('alex', '30', 'M'),
    @('ava', '25', 'F')
)

$people | Where-Object { $_[1] -lt '25' -and $_[2] -eq 'M' } | ForEach-Object { $_[0] }

# Results in:
#
# adam
# andy
```

Or using a traditional `foreach` loop with an `if` statement:

```sh
foreach($array in $people) {
    if($array[1] -lt 25 -and $array[2] -eq 'M') {
        $array[0]
    }
}
```

However as recommended in previous answer, a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) might be more suitable for this (even though the syntax is a bit more complicated):

```sh
$people = @{
    M = @{
        24 = 'adam'
        20 = 'andy'
        30 = 'alex'
    }
    F = @{
        25 = 'ava'
    }
}

$people['M'][$people['M'].Keys -lt 25]
```

Comment: It is you again! Thank you again! You're the best! Unfortunately, Im not gonna be able to use hash tables anymore for this one as I would have lots of unique values. I just couldnt come up with the right example. But for your answer is perfect!

Comment: @Pa3k.m my pleasure, I added the `foreach` example (I would personally use that as it is faster and in my eyes, the syntax is easier to understand)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the answer involving ForEach-Object of course.  The only possible issue with this (depending on what you are trying to do with that data) is that a *ForEach-Object* will execute each record of data individually.

Another way is to create the object you want specifically then use a standard foreach().

```
$people = @(
 @('adam', '24', 'M')
 @('andy', '20', 'M')
 @('alex', '30', 'M')
 @('ava', '25', 'F')
)

$filteredPeople = $people | Where-Object { $_[1] -lt '25' -and $_[2] -eq 'M'}

foreach($person in $$filteredPeople) {

#stuff

}
```

This will do the same functionality on the whole object.

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72294264/45375) solves your problem well.

Let me offer an alternative that uses a PowerShell v5+ custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) to model the instances of your array, which makes for more descriptive, and type-safe, access to each person's properties:

```sh
# Define a [Person] class with a constructor that fills all properties.
class Person {
  [string] $Name
  [int]    $Age
  [char]   $Sex
  Person([string] $name, [int] $age, [char] $sex) { 
    $this.Name = $name; $this.Age = $age; $this.Sex = $sex
  }
}

# Create an array of [Person] instances.
$people = @(
 [Person]::new('adam', '24', 'M')
 [Person]::new('andy', '20', 'M')
 [Person]::new('alex', '30', 'M')
 [Person]::new('ava', '25', 'F')
)

# Filter the array via the .Where() array method.
$people.Where({ $_.Age -lt 25 -and $_.Sex -eq 'M' })
```

Output:

```sh
Name Age Sex
---- --- ---
adam  24   M
andy  20   M
```

If you were interested in, say, only the `.Name` property values, simply append `.Name` to the last command above, which returns array `'adam', 'andy'`, courtesy of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature.

Note the use of the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), which - for collections already in memory - is a more efficient alternative to the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet; that said, a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) performs best.